# update string format of TextBox on lost focus

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have a `TextBox` defined in my XAML as:

```
<TextBox x:Name="AmountDueTextBox"
         Width="250"
         RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="BalanceTextBox"
         RelativePanel.Below="BalanceTextBox"
         Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.CurrentInvoice.AmountDue, 
                       Mode=TwoWay, 
                       Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, 
                                  ConverterParameter='{}{0:N}'}" />
```

The converter is applied when I <kbd>TAB</kbd> out of the `TextBox`, but if I click away, the string will not be formatted automatically. I have read similar questions, but haven't seen any solution. As I mentioned, it works properly when tabbing out, but not normal `LostFocus`.

I am using Template 10 in a Universal Windows Project. Here is the `StringFormatConverter` from Template 10:

```
public class StringFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var format = (parameter as string) ?? Format;
        if (format == null)
            return value;

        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(language))
        {
            return string.Format(format, value);
        }    

        try
        {
            var culture = new CultureInfo(language);
            return string.Format(culture, format, value);
        }
        catch
        {
            return string.Format(format, value);
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string Format { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT** Added custom `ConvertBack` method:

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    if (value is string)
    {
        decimal returnDecimal;
        if (decimal.TryParse(value as string, out returnDecimal))
        {
            return returnDecimal;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Can you show more detail about your `StringFormatConverter`.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I have edited the post to include the `StringFormatConverter` code.

Comment: When you TAB out or click away of  the TextBox  the `ConvertBack` method will be executed for `TwoWay` Binding.  As far as I can see it `throw new NotImplementedException`?

Comment: Sorry about that - I just put the default `StringFormatConverter` from Template 10, I didn't have my project in front of me to realize that I had a custom `ConvertBack` method implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code and found nothing wrong. I can't reproduce your issue. Since your code is not the whole, I complete your code and create a demo which can run successfully. Could you please try uninstall the app in your machine, clean the solution and redeploy it? If it doesn’t work. Please have a try of my [demo](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/WindowsApp2.git) and compare with your project if something is different with.

```cs
public class DateToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members
    public string Format { get; set; }
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {

        var format = (parameter as string) ?? Format;
        if (format == null)
            return value;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(language))
        {
            return string.Format(format, value);
        }

        try
        {
            var culture = new CultureInfo(language);
            return string.Format(culture, format, value);
        }
        catch
        {
            return string.Format(format, value);
        }
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            decimal returnDecimal;
            if (decimal.TryParse(value as string, out returnDecimal))
            {
                return returnDecimal;
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
  #endregion
}
```

Comment: Same behavior with your app. If I <TAB> out of the `TextBox`, it will format the number, but if I click into a different `TextBox`, then the formatting is not applied.

Comment: I tried to follow your description(*click into a different TextBox*), but did not reproduce your issue. Have you tried running your app on other computers?

Comment: I noticed that it does seem to work in some contexts. I will just need to see what the issue is, maybe there is something going on with the underlying object that I am binding to. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue in my case was that my `View` didn't know it's `DataContext` because it wasn't tied to the `ViewModel`. In one of my `View`s, I had added a `DependencyProperty` to be able to pass the same `ViewModel` to multiple child `View`s that are interchangeable. Here is the `DependencyProperty` that I had to add to get it to work properly:

```
public sealed partial class PaymentView : UserControl
{
    public InvoiceDetailsPageViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (InvoiceDetailsPageViewModel)GetValue(ViewModelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ViewModel", typeof(InvoiceDetailsPageViewModel), typeof(PaymentView), null);

    public PaymentView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContextChanged += (s, e) => this.Bindings.Update();
    }
}
```

My `InvoiceDetailsPage` has two different `Views`: a `PaymentView` and an `InvoiceView`. I needed to add the `DependencyProperty` to the child `Views` (`UserControl`s in this case). Now I can use `x:Bind`, and my `StringFormatConverter` works properly.